# For Paypal website payments standard, Do I need to create add to cart buttons using my client's account?

Tags: paypal

I wish to use Paypal web site payments standard on one of my clients webpages.

It's a simple static site, so I do not wish to use a e-commerce package.

I'm creating test code using my own paypal account.

But when it comes to creating the real buttons, will I need to login using my clients login details?

I'm guessing that it would be easier to do this using website payments pro - as I could use the API and then towards the end of development switch it to the client's account / token (i'm not sure of the terminology, but understand the concept).

In an ideal world, I'm hoping for something similar to Google adwords management accounts, where I can manage my clients' sub-accounts.

I'd rather not have to login as my client and instead be able to the work from my own account.
Is there a way of achieving this? Or a development workflow anyone reccomends?

Feel free to talk geeky to me, I'm a developer - but just don't have much experiance with paypal.

-thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

Here is a link out to [PayPal's developer documentation for shopping cart buttons](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_paypal_shopping_cart) - from the look of it, you *will* need to create buttons using the client's PayPal account (though it's probably just a matter of finding the right tokens to replace in the HTML forms and links your client's site displays).

Comment: As I recall (it's been like 8 years since I touched PayPal), some of the product information (e.g. the product name and product code) is in the generated code, but I think some of it is held on PayPal's end (like the price), so I'm not sure if it's just a matter of using the client's PayPal ID.

Comment: @Lèse majesté - It has been about six years for me ... hesitant to do more than link to the docs given that there may have been "major advancements" in the interim :)

Comment: @Lèse majesté I believe you have a choice as to how much information is stored at PayPal's end (within your account). By storing all the information 'in the button' at PayPal's end it is deemed more secure. However, you can specify _everything_ as parameters in the HTML itself (including the price), which gives you a lot of flexibility, but it's less secure. I don't think you _need_ to create the buttons within the account itself, if you choose to specify all the parameters in the HTML.